# Objective C member in C++ class

Tags: c++, objective-c, function, member

Is it possible to have a objective c member in a c++ class

```
@interface ObjectiveCClass : UIViewController  {

    int someVarialbe;

}
- (void)someFunction;

@end


class CPlusPlusClass{
      ObjectiveCClass obj;          // have a objective c member

      void doSomething(){
           obj.someFunction;        // and call a objective c method
       }
};
```

Any guidance would really be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create header files that can be shared between obj-c and cpp code, you could use the compiler predefined macros to do something like:

```
// A .h file defining a objc class and a paired cpp class
// The implementation for both the objective C class and CPP class
// MUST be in a paired .mm file
#pragma once

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#else
#include <objc/objc.h>
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__

@interface ObjectiveCClass :
...

typedef ObjectiveCClass* ObjectiveCClassRef;

#else

typedef id ObjectiveCClassRef;

#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus

class CPlusPlusClass {
  ObjectiveCClassRef obj;

  void doSomethind();
};

#endif
```

Im not 100% sure its legal to have ObjectiveCClassRef change type like that between c/cpp and obj-c builds.
But `id` is a c/cpp compatible type defined in the objective C header files as capable of storing an objective C class pointer, and, when used in .m or .mm files, allows you to call the object directly using objective C syntax.

Comment: When i add the 


#include "ObjectiveCClass.h"  


to the c++ file i get 9000 errors, like:

Expected unqualified-id before '-' token


and


Stray '@' in program

Comment: Header Files that are going to be shared  between .cc / .cpp and /mm files need to be sanitized. You can't use any of objective-Cs @ directives in such a header file.

Comment: So what does a objective-c class have to look like so i can have a member of it in a c++ class. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i hope thats a compilment :P its rare one gets to see objective-c / cpp interop questions.

Comment: So that compiles but how do i go about accessing CPlusPlusClass from another c++ class. I still have to #include the "ObjectiveCClass.h", which throws all those errors. Edit. Turn all the .cpp to .mm should sort it out

Comment: You don't need to convert all the cpp to mm. the macro's should take care of things and let you #include the cppc.h from cpp or mm files.

Answer (score 2):

There's a dialect of Objective-C called Objective-C++ that is interoperable with C++ the same way that Objective-C is interoperable with C. You can either change the setting for the file to be Objective-C++ or change the extension to ".mm". You'll still need to access Objective-C objects through pointers and do the alloc-init dance and all that, of course.